# Optimize the use of BigQuery resources to load 2 million JSON files from GCS using Google Dataflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a vast database comprised of ~2.4 million JSON files that by themselves contain several records. I've created a simple apache-beam data pipeline (shown below) that follows these steps:

- Read data from a GCS bucket using a glob pattern.
- Extract records from JSON data.
- Transform data: convert dictionaries to JSON strings, parse timestamps, others.
- Write to BigQuery.

```py
# Pipeline
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

# Read
files = p | 'get_data' >> ReadFromText(files_pattern)

# Transform
output = (files
          | 'extract_records' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractRecordsFn())
          | 'transform_data' >> beam.ParDo(TransformDataFn()))

# Write
output | 'write_data' >> WriteToBigQuery(table=known_args.table,
                                         create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                         write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_EMPTY,
                                         insert_retry_strategy='RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR',
                                         temp_file_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON')

# Run
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

I've tested this pipeline with a minimal sample dataset and is working as expected. But I'm pretty doubtful regarding the optimal use of BigQuery resources and quotas. The [batch load quotas are very restrictive](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs), and due to the massive amount of files to parse and load, I want to know if I'm missing some settings that could guarantee the pipeline will respect the quotas and run optimally. I don't want to exceed the quotas as I am running other loads to BigQuery in the same project.

I haven't finished understanding some parameters of the `WriteToBigQuery()` transform, specifically `batch_size`, `max_file_size`, and `max_files_per_bundle`, or if they could help to optimize the load jobs to BigQuery. Could you help me with this?

**Update**

I'm not only concerned about BigQuery quotas, but GCP quotas of other resources used by this pipeline are also a matter of concern.

I tried to run my simple pipeline over the target data (~2.4 million files), but I'm receiving the following warning message:

> Project [my-project] has insufficient quota(s) to execute this workflow with 1 instances in region us-central1. Quota summary (required/available): 1/16 instances, 1/16 CPUs, 250/2096 disk GB, 0/500 SSD disk GB, 1/99 instance groups, 1/49 managed instance groups, 1/99 instance templates, 1/0 in-use IP addresses. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas about requesting more quota.

I don't understand that message completely. The process activated 8 workers successfully and is using 8 from the 8 available in-use IP addresses. Is this a problem? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about load job quotas, you can try streaming data into bigquery that comes with a less [restrictive quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts).

To achieve what you want to do, you can try the Google provided templates or just refer to their code.

- [Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery (Stream)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#gcstexttobigquerystream) [[code](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#expandable-7)]
- [Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery (Batch)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttobigquery)

And last but not the least, more detailed information can be found on the [Google BigQuery I/O connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/).

Comment: I going to try the streaming of data. I was thinking that there are some settings in the `DataflowRunner` and the BigQuery module, that could allow me to manage resources in an optimal way.